# I am returning a JSON response from this code and I get [ ]

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-views, jsonresponse

I am trying to get a all model instances related to a driver from another model as shown looping through driver queryset, then return it all in json format. But I am getting an [ ] a result.

```
  elif request.method == "POST":
    pull_tegas_serializer = TegaSerializer(data=request.data)
    if pull_tegas_serializer.is_valid():
        check_for_tegas_request = request.data
        rafiki_number = check_for_tegas_request['rafiki_number']

        def get_rafiki(rafiki_number):
            rafiki_got = RafikiRegistrationCodeModel.objects.filter(phone_number=rafiki_number)
            return rafiki_got.first(), rafiki_got.exists()

        def fetch_rafiki_profile():
            fetched_profile = RafikiProfileModel.objects.filter(rafiki_number=get_rafiki(rafiki_number)[0])
            return fetched_profile.first(), fetched_profile.exists()

        def get_rafiki_driver_session_record():
            rafiki_driver_session_record = RafikiDriverSession.objects.filter(rafiki_number=fetch_rafiki_profile()[0])
            return rafiki_driver_session_record.first(), rafiki_driver_session_record.exists

        rafiki_driver_sessions = RafikiDriverSession.objects.filter(rafiki_number=fetch_rafiki_profile()[0])

        for rafikidriversession in rafiki_driver_sessions:
            fetched_tega = Tega.objects.filter(driver_profile=rafikidriversession.drivers_profile)
            print (rafikidriversession.rafiki_number, rafikidriversession.drivers_profile)
            print (fetched_tega)
            tega_pulled_serializer = TegaSerializer(fetched_tega, many=True)
        return Response(tega_pulled_serializer.data)
    return Response(pull_tegas_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So after revising my executions. I realized its returning only data from the last instance of the for loop execution and not all of the data from the for loop instances. Is there a way I can save each time a loop is complete and then get those results to be parsed to json response?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to help you, please provide a [mcve] as text in your question. This code example should include enough details that we can easily understand what you are trying to do but not contain any unnecessary information that has nothing to do with yoru question.

Comment: I hope the question is fine now. Thanks Code-Apprentice @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Thanks for posting the code as text instead of a link to a screenshot. However, the code has several compiler errors: indentation is not correct, there are many undefined variables and class names, and there is a `return` without a `def` for a function.

Comment: Please read the link in my first comment.

Comment: Why are you defining functions inside an `if` block?  That's quite unusual.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am beginner in stackoverflow. Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: @JohnGordon they are dependent on some data arguments that are provided only after the if function. Is there any suggestion that you may offer?

Comment: `get_rafiki()` takes `rafiki_number` as a parameter, but that's just a name.  You could just as well call the parameter `batman` or `spaghetti`.  There is no explicit link between the `rafiki_number` parameter and the local variable of the same name.  As far as I can see, there's no reason `get_rafiki()` has to be defined within the if block.

Comment: @JohnGordon thanks for the comment.. but may you help me identify why I am getting an empty JSON response on the return Response.

Comment: So after revising my executions. I realized its returning only data from the last instance of the for loop execution and not all of the data from the for loop instances. Is there a way I can save each time a loop is complete and then get those results to be parsed to json response? @JohnGordon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're replacing `tega_pulled_serializer` each time through the loop. It should be a list that you append to each time through the loop.

```
        tega_pulled_serializer = []
        for rafikidriversession in rafiki_driver_sessions:
            fetched_tega = Tega.objects.filter(driver_profile=rafikidriversession.drivers_profile)
            print (rafikidriversession.rafiki_number, rafikidriversession.drivers_profile)
            print (fetched_tega)
            tega_pulled_serializer.append(TegaSerializer(fetched_tega, many=True).data)
        return Response(tega_pulled_serializer)
```